# How to show a different desktop image to screen capturing applications?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background, screenshot, screencast, shutter

I often take screenshots with `shutter` and do screen recordings with other applications, and sometimes I have my desktop picture set to something private that I don't want people looking at my screencasts or screenshots to see... So I end up having to temporarily change my desktop picture, and this is getting rather annoying... So I was wondering if there is a way to make it so that the screen capturing applications see a different desktop picture to the actual one I have set? So that I don't have to change the desktop picture, but the capturing applications just see it as another which I have specified? I would at least like it for `shutter` if not all screen capturing applications.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: Please don't create new dupe tags. ("desktop-picture" instead of "background"). But other than that, +1 for a new level of paranoia! :D

Comment: I think the only option is to write a script that runs before and after launching the screenshot application and that changes the background. You probably can't emulate a different background for just one application. Or use multiple desktop workspaces and assign a separate background to each of them. Then you can have one non-private workspace for screenshooting etc.

Comment: @ByteCommander: I didn't find the `background` tag... :D

Comment: @ByteCommander: So there is no way at all just to feed it in another desktop background?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda shutter takes a pixel orientated image of your desktop, in which your wallpaper is not a separate layer. Impossible to separate. Only option is indeed to start up the screenshot - taking application via a wrapper, and automatically change back on exit.

Comment: I thought the same as @JacobVlijm, how would you want to separate it? Even if the application could/would detect where the background is visible and where it is covered by a window etc., you would run into trouble with semi-transparent windows.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Is there no way then of taking the opposite approach and making it so that my desktop picture does actually change to something else when `shutter` is started, and changes back to what it was previously when it closes, but instead I am shown a desktop picture which is not actually there? That's probably not possible and it sounds odd, but is there no way of changing the desktop for all applications except what I see?

Comment: That's probably almost the same as what I said before though... So if it has to just change the desktop picture when `shutter` launches, and then change it back to the original one when `shutter` exists, then so be it.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda *that* is very well possible!

Comment: @JacobVlijm: I assume you mean the last one I mentioned, if so, please remember that I have shutter open and minimized to the AppIndicator icon bar thing the whole time, so it should only actually do it when I am about to take a screenshot.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Ai, then do you open the shutter window before taking a screen shot?

Comment: @JacobVlijm: I just click on the icon in the AppIndicator bar and select what kind of screenshot I would like to make.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda That is a complicated problem. I need to think... and find a way to intercept the action somehow.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: Could you perhaps monitor the activity of the program somehow?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I hope so, but even then, the shot most likely id taken before.

Comment: "sometimes I have my desktop picture set to something private"? Don't do that.

Comment: @waltinator: I don't do it very often, but sometimes the picture looks so nice there that I just want to set it for a while.

Comment: I'm sure a lot of people do this (have something private as their wallpaper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Toggle your wallpaper

Not literally what you asked for, yet the best option, as far as I can see: a key short cut to toggle between your *usual* wallpaper (the script will find out), and a pre- chosen wallpaper, to be set in the head of the script.

*My secret wallpaper: (which I don't want people to see)* **:)**

[image: Wubuntu]

*Press the shortcut, My "public" wallpaper is set. Take the screenshot:*

[image: Froggy]

*Press the shortcut again:*

[image: Wubuntu]

#### Why this seems the best option

- In your question you mention automatically "replacing" the wallpaper in the screen shot (or recording), by another wallpaper. However, all applications you mention make a recording in one layer of pixels. Separating wallpaper and foreground is quite impossible, unless you do it manually (which is a demanding job).
- In comments, we spoke about automatically set another wallpaper once the screen shot is (going to be) taken, but since you run `Shutter` in the background continuously, *and* you run the command from its panel menu, it seems impossible to find a trigger. The `pid` of `Shutter` obviously isn't, and the menu does not appear as a window in the output of `wmctrl -l`
- Even *if* we could find a child process of `Shutter` once the screen shot is being taken, the action would have taken place before we can change the wallpaper.

#### So...

Below a script to use under a short cut key, to toggle your wallpaper:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os

# --- set your replacement- wallpaper below
image = "/path/to/your/image"
# ---

currwall = os.environ["HOME"] + "/.set_wall"
key = [
    "gsettings ",
    "get ", "set ",
    "org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri",
    ]

def get(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", command]).decode("utf-8").strip()

def run(command):
    subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command])

if not os.path.exists(currwall):
    # save the (path to the) currently used wallpaper to an invisible file
    cmd = key[0]+key[1]+key[-1]
    open(currwall, "wt").write(get(cmd))
    # set the temporary wallaper
    cmd = key[0]+key[2]+key[-1]+" 'file://"+image+"'"
else:
    # read the file, restore the original wallpaper
    cmd = key[0]+key[2]+key[-1]+" "+open(currwall).read()
    # remove the temporary file
    os.remove(currwall)
run(cmd)
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `toggle_wallpaper.py`
2. In the head section of the script, set the secondary wallpaper, that should replace the usual one.

   ```
   # --- set your replacement- wallpaper below
   image = "/path/to/your/image"
   # ---
   ```
3. Test- run the script with the command:

   ```
   python_3 /path/to/toggle_wallpaper.py
   ```

   (two times to set the secondary- and restore the original wallpaper)
4. Add the command to a shortcut key: choose: <kbd>System Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Keyboard</kbd> → <kbd>Shortcuts</kbd> → <kbd>Custom Shortcuts</kbd>. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> and add the command:

   ```
   python_3 /path/to/toggle_wallpaper.py
   ```

Comment: Great answer! And I love your secret wallpaper by the way! ;)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda haha, I was looking for a way to make it cheerful :)

Comment: @Fabby thanks for the edit :) Here we call Windows: *Windhoos*  :)